# Facing an error on zsh while using pgcli on Mac OS 12

Tags: python-2.7, zsh

I am using M1 Macbook Air. Mac OS 12.0.1 monterey

```
$ pgcli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logging/__init__.py", line 609, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logging/__init__.py", line 402, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: u'threadName'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pgcli", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pgcli==1.7.0', 'console_scripts', 'pgcli')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgcli/main.py", line 867, in cli
    pgcli.run_cli()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgcli/main.py", line 470, in run_cli
    self.cli = self._build_cli(history)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgcli/main.py", line 576, in _build_cli
    style=style_factory(self.syntax_style, self.cli_style),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgcli/pgstyle.py", line 14, in style_factory
    for x, y in cli_style.items()])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/token.py", line 117, in string_to_tokentype
    node = getattr(node, item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/token.py", line 37, in __getattr__
    return tuple.__getattribute__(self, val)
AttributeError: '_TokenType' object has no attribute 'completion-menu'
```

Any idea what might be causing this error?
pip install of pygments is on 2.5.2, up to date.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, it's working for me on Macos 12.0.1, with python 3.8 and  homebrew installed pgcli (encountered errors with pip install).